# Data variable undefined from computed Vue

Tags: vue.js

I think im not understanding something properly or is an obvious oversight but I cant access values returned from  my data() function in my Vue component's computed properties. From my below code i am trying to return a computed property newmessage but it is saying that message is undefined and so is everything else in data if i try. Appreciate any help :)

```
<script>
  export default {
    props:['alertdata'],
    data () {
      return {
        message: 'hello',
        expanded: [],
        singleExpand: false,
        alertHeaders: [
          {
            text: 'Rule Number',
            align: 'start',
            sortable: false,
            value: 'RuleNumber',
          },
          
          { text: 'Date', value: 'DateCreated' },
          { text: 'Amount', value: 'Amount' },

        ],
        alerts: this.alertdata,
        transactions : this.alertdata.detail,     
      }
    },
    computed: {
        newmessage : function() { 
        return message.reverse()
        }
      
    }

  }
  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, inside methods, or computed properties or lifecycle handlers in Vue, you will use `this` to refer the component to which the method/computed/handler is attached. `this` refers to the context in which the function is currently executing.

in your case you need to add `this` before message

```
computed: {
    newmessage : function() { 
    return this.message.reverse()
    }
```

Comment: Of course haha - Ive been staring at the screen for too long i think! Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to property defined in `data` with `this` keyword:

```js
newmessage : function() { 
  return this.message.reverse()
}
```